# What is the difference between ERL and EA by considering it as RL?

Tags: reinforcement-learning, evolutionary-algorithm

What is the difference between
Evolutionary Reinforcement Learning and
Evolutionary Algorithm by considering it as Reinforcement Learning?

I am trying to understand the basics of EA where how can I improve issues of EA using RL but most of the research is based on using ERL and where RL issues can be solved using EA or ES for example multiple optimization problems but I want EA as my baseline using RL so that's why I am in too much confusion in this situation can anyone please help me to find difference.
I am also sharing previous research based on ERL but I want it's opposite that hoe can improve EA issues using RL

[Shauharda Khadka, Kagan Tumer: *Evolutionary Reinforcement Learning*, 2018](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Shauharda-Khadka/publication/325282913_Evolutionary_Reinforcement_Learning/links/5b19a73da6fdcca67b65f89f/Evolutionary-Reinforcement-Learning.pdf)

[Mădălina M. Drugan: *Reinforcement learning versus evolutionary computation: asurvey on hybrid algorithms*, 2018](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Madalina-Drugan/publication/324082363_Reinforcement_learning_versus_evolutionary_computation_A_survey_on_hybrid_algorithms/links/5ac49643458515564eaf6bac/Reinforcement-learning-versus-evolutionary-computation-A-survey-on-hybrid-algorithms.pdf)

[Shauharda Khadka, Kagan Tumer: *Evolution-Guided Policy Gradient in Reinforcement Learning*, 2018](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1805.07917.pdf)

Comment: stack**overflow** may not be the best site to ask this question. See [Which computer science / programming Stack Exchange sites do I post on?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/129598/which-computer-science-programming-stack-exchange-sites-do-i-post-on?r=SearchResults&s=2|351.0732)

Comment: (`that hoe` doesn't quite look intended)